# MS-Access Looking up and updating records based on values in form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've learned a lot in Access over the last month or so but am now have trouble resolving an issue that I don't know how to approach.  I'm sure there's a simple solution but I need help being pointed in the right direction.  Here's the background:

This problem deals with three forms:

1. frmProject - Lists project details it has a
2. subfrmMilestones - Milestone details
3. frmProjMsgBox - Collects info to pass to Project table

I have it set that when I click OK on ProjectMsgBox it passes the information to the Project form and starts the creation of a new record.

1. tblProject stores all details related to projects
2. tblMilestones stores all details on milestones, contains key for tblProject
3. tblMilestones_Inf stores a list of common milestones based on project type, has key for tblProjectType, which is on tblProject

My Problem -

When I click okay on the ProjectMsgBox form, I would like it to also look up milestones from tblMilestones_Inf and insert into tblMilestones.  I also need to assign the Project_ID that on the form to the creates.  What is the best way to go about this?

I've tried a few things in VBA but haven't had success.  I can create a query that pulls the milestones in but don't know how to update the milestone table with the relationship to the project table.

I can provide more details but wasn't sure what is helpful and what is not.  I'm more or less looking for a resource (or keywords to search) so I can figure this out on my own

Thank you!

UPDATE:

1. tblProject has 1 to many relationship with tblMilestones
2. tblProjectType has 1 to many relationship with tblMilestones_Inf

Once I hit okay on the frmProjMsgBox it fills out text boxes that have controls on frmProject to create the parent record (i think that's the term) in tblProject.  This works well.  I would like access to go out to the tblMilestones_Inf and match the project type (child record?).  It would then add 4-5 records based on matching ProjectType on the Milestone_Inf table.  **I don't want code, but maybe actions/keywords to lookup so I can figure this out on my own.**  I'll post some of my code later that tries to achieve this.

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into DLookup. I had VBA use recordset to pull info in, I should have saved it for this portion.  I'll update based on your questions tonight when I have time.  I've very new so I was hoping someone would help brainstorm some things to lookup (like Dlookup).  I wasn't looking for code but I'm new enough to not even know the right way to ask a question sometimes.  It is fun to figure things out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look into Query Defs, you can use those to change the SQL statement of your queries from VBA. So if you have something like:

```
MyQryDef.SQL = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyIndex = " & MyControl.Value & ";"
```

and your control value is set to 5, you then use the execute statement and your Query SQL will then read:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyIndex = 5;
```

There's a few more lines you will have to look up to make this work, but this is a very basic example.